# Using Activity methods in a non activity class

Tags: java, android

I am trying to write a table out to an Activity via a non Activity class and I'm having trouble accessing the Activity methods to do so.
I do pass in the Activity via the constructor, but methods like `findViewById` still don't work.
I think that I need to `setContextView`.

Is this approach correct and if so, what do I put in as the argument for `setContextView` inside my class and where do I do that at?

Below is the approach I am taking, but I am not sure how to use `setContextView` so that the Activity methods like `findViewById` can be used.

```
MyClass instance = new MyClass(this);

public class MyClass {
    public Activity activity;

    public MyClass(Activity _activity){
        this.activity = _activity;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to question, but is your code missing a brace?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, you can call all the activity methods like that:

```
activity.findVewById(R.xxx.xxx);
activity.getResrouces();
etc...
```

Comment: Thanks.  I will give it a shot.  One question does the argument inside findViewById(R.xxx.xxx); need to be the same as for the Activity that you are passing activity as an argument for?

Comment: Yes, but since you are calling it from a different class, you have to call it from the activity's variable as mentioned in my answer.

Comment: The above answers to my questions does seem to work but. when I try to implement the following code to dynamically build the table

Comment: So, after I implement the following how do I use the following code. TableRow tr_head = new TableRow(this);
tr_head.setId(10);
tr_head.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
tr_head.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); setId, SetBackgroundColor, etc. are unresolved symbols.